# How do I select Edge profile launched when debugging in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: microsoft-edge, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2022 which Edge profile to launch when debugging a docker app?

They seem to have removed the "Browse With" option that let you define a new browser with parameters and only allow you select Edge, Chrome, Firefox, etc. with not parameters.

My default profile is "Work", which uses the new Edge for business but Visual Studio keeps launching my personal profile. This is problematic as all my saved passwords that I need to use when debugging are in the "Work" profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which type of project are you debugging？

To configure Visual Studio to launch the browser with your 'work' profile you'll need to:

1. Go to the Browse with... option: （Can you see this option? ）

[image]

2. Click Add... a new browser:

[image]

3. Configure the path to your browser, and use a custom --user-data-dir argument pointing to your user data folder

[image]
In my PC they are:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe
> --user-data-dir="C:\Users\AppData\local\Microsoft\Edge Beta\User Data"

4. And then optionally set it as the Default browser if you choose to.
5. Browse with your 'work' profile.

Comment: Aha...the "Browse With..." option hasn't been removed, it just disappears if you select "docker-compose" as the startup project.
I selected a different project and then it allowed me to add the browser. When I switched back to the docker-compose project, I could now select this new browser 

Comment: It seems that the path provided by Elin is missing the username between `Users` and `AppData`.

Answer (score 3):

Elin's answer will launch the browser with the default profile. However, if your goal is to launch in a *specific* profile, then you should use the `--profile-directory` argument.

You can find the profile directory for any profile using the PowerShell snippet below. It will list all Edge profiles by profile name and folder name.

```
$EdgeProfiles = gci "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\" -Filter "Profile*"

ForEach($EdgeProfile in $EdgeProfiles.Name) { 
  $Preferences = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\$EdgeProfile\Preferences"
  $Data = (ConvertFrom-Json (Get-content $Preferences -Raw))
  $profileName = $Data.Profile.Name
  "$profileName,$EdgeProfile"
}
```

Then the argument textbox in Visual Studio would contain this text:

`--profile-directory="Profile 4"`

assuming that the profile you wish the launch with is in the `Profile 4` folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, my work account does not appear in the list of profiles, only my personal account.
Looks like they changed the way work profiles work when they added that new Edge for business feature.